# How to center gridView items in Flutter?

Tags: gridview, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a 4*4 grid view, but sometimes instead of 16 items there might only be 15 items, to the last row looks not so nice...

I am wondered is there any way to center items in gridView row?
Or there might be some other solution which can solve my task?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot

Answer (score 23, accepted):

as an option you can use Wrap widget instead of Grid
here is an example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Title')),
        body: AlignedGrid(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AlignedGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final double runSpacing = 4;
  final double spacing = 4;
  final int listSize = 15;
  final columns = 4;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final w = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - runSpacing * (columns - 1)) / columns;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Wrap(
        runSpacing: runSpacing,
        spacing: spacing,
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        children: List.generate(listSize, (index) {
          return Container(
            width: w,
            height: w,
            color: Colors.green[200],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

change `alignment` property as you wish 
e.g. `WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly`