# Centering the last row of items in a flutter gridview

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

I have a dynamic list of items I am outputting into a `GridView.count` constructor with a mainAxisCount of 2 (2 column grid). If the list length is odd, the last row will only contain a single item. I want this single item to be centered on the screen, rather than being aligned with the first column. Can this be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955051/how-to-center-gridview-items-in-flutter/57955465#57955465

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75280416/horizontally-center-last-odd-item-of-gridview-or-listview-in-flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two answers considering [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view). Although it is a nice package, I think it does much more than you want.

I am providing a more manual, custom implementation.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

/// A [SliverGridLayout] that provide a way to customize the children geometry.
class SliverGridWithCustomGeometryLayout extends SliverGridRegularTileLayout {
  /// The builder for each child geometry.
  final SliverGridGeometry Function(
    int index,
    SliverGridRegularTileLayout layout,
  ) geometryBuilder;

  SliverGridWithCustomGeometryLayout({
    @required this.geometryBuilder,
    @required int crossAxisCount,
    @required double mainAxisStride,
    @required double crossAxisStride,
    @required double childMainAxisExtent,
    @required double childCrossAxisExtent,
    @required bool reverseCrossAxis,
  })  : assert(geometryBuilder != null),
        assert(crossAxisCount != null && crossAxisCount > 0),
        assert(mainAxisStride != null && mainAxisStride >= 0),
        assert(crossAxisStride != null && crossAxisStride >= 0),
        assert(childMainAxisExtent != null && childMainAxisExtent >= 0),
        assert(childCrossAxisExtent != null && childCrossAxisExtent >= 0),
        assert(reverseCrossAxis != null),
        super(
          crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
          mainAxisStride: mainAxisStride,
          crossAxisStride: crossAxisStride,
          childMainAxisExtent: childMainAxisExtent,
          childCrossAxisExtent: childCrossAxisExtent,
          reverseCrossAxis: reverseCrossAxis,
        );

  @override
  SliverGridGeometry getGeometryForChildIndex(int index) {
    return geometryBuilder(index, this);
  }
}

/// Creates grid layouts with a fixed number of tiles in the cross axis, such
/// that fhe last element, if the grid item count is odd, is centralized.
class SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndCentralizedLastElement
    extends SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount {
  /// The total number of itens in the layout.
  final int itemCount;

  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndCentralizedLastElement({
    @required this.itemCount,
    @required int crossAxisCount,
    double mainAxisSpacing = 0.0,
    double crossAxisSpacing = 0.0,
    double childAspectRatio = 1.0,
  })  : assert(itemCount != null && itemCount > 0),
        assert(crossAxisCount != null && crossAxisCount > 0),
        assert(mainAxisSpacing != null && mainAxisSpacing >= 0),
        assert(crossAxisSpacing != null && crossAxisSpacing >= 0),
        assert(childAspectRatio != null && childAspectRatio > 0),
        super(
          crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
          mainAxisSpacing: mainAxisSpacing,
          crossAxisSpacing: crossAxisSpacing,
          childAspectRatio: childAspectRatio,
        );

  bool _debugAssertIsValid() {
    assert(crossAxisCount > 0);
    assert(mainAxisSpacing >= 0.0);
    assert(crossAxisSpacing >= 0.0);
    assert(childAspectRatio > 0.0);
    return true;
  }

  @override
  SliverGridLayout getLayout(SliverConstraints constraints) {
    assert(_debugAssertIsValid());
    final usableCrossAxisExtent = max(
      0.0,
      constraints.crossAxisExtent - crossAxisSpacing * (crossAxisCount - 1),
    );
    final childCrossAxisExtent = usableCrossAxisExtent / crossAxisCount;
    final childMainAxisExtent = childCrossAxisExtent / childAspectRatio;
    return SliverGridWithCustomGeometryLayout(
      geometryBuilder: (index, layout) {
        return SliverGridGeometry(
          scrollOffset: (index ~/ crossAxisCount) * layout.mainAxisStride,
          crossAxisOffset: itemCount.isOdd && index == itemCount - 1
              ? layout.crossAxisStride / 2
              : _getOffsetFromStartInCrossAxis(index, layout),
          mainAxisExtent: childMainAxisExtent,
          crossAxisExtent: childCrossAxisExtent,
        );
      },
      crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
      mainAxisStride: childMainAxisExtent + mainAxisSpacing,
      crossAxisStride: childCrossAxisExtent + crossAxisSpacing,
      childMainAxisExtent: childMainAxisExtent,
      childCrossAxisExtent: childCrossAxisExtent,
      reverseCrossAxis: axisDirectionIsReversed(constraints.crossAxisDirection),
    );
  }

  double _getOffsetFromStartInCrossAxis(
    int index,
    SliverGridRegularTileLayout layout,
  ) {
    final crossAxisStart = (index % crossAxisCount) * layout.crossAxisStride;

    if (layout.reverseCrossAxis) {
      return crossAxisCount * layout.crossAxisStride -
          crossAxisStart -
          layout.childCrossAxisExtent -
          (layout.crossAxisStride - layout.childCrossAxisExtent);
    }
    return crossAxisStart;
  }
}
```

### Explanation

Explaining a little, what this code is doing is that it is a custom implementation of `SliverGridLayout`, which is the type of class that tells Flutter how to position children on a grid layout.

The more important method here is `getGeometryForChildIndex`. This is the method that says where each child should be positioned, based on its `index`. Note, however, that we are exposing this method through a parameter to the next class I'll be talking about.

The next class we implement is `SliverGridDelegate`. We have to make a custom implementation to use `SliverGridWithCustomGeometryLayout`, as there's no other way to make a delegate use a specific `SliverGridLayout`. Here we used our parameter `geometryBuilder` to delegate to it the role of returning a `SliverGridGeometry`.

This implementation of `geometryBuilder` is where all the magic happens. It is basically a copy of the original `SliverGridRegularTileLayout` method, but with one change. We check if the index of the element is even and if it is also the last one. If both checks pass, we return a centered position. Else, we return the position it would have anyway.

To use our solution, just pass it to the `gridDelegate` parameter on a `GridView`. Example:

```dart
GridView.builder(
    itemCount: 9,
    itemBuilder: (_, __) =>
        Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.red),
    gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndCentralizedLastElement(
            itemCount: checklist.sections.length(),
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 0.825,
        ),
)
```

### Disclaimer

This solution was not exhaustively tested, and I posted it here only to one have the idea about how to make it. However, I am using it in production code. If I eventually find any problem with it, I'll edit here.

Comment: Did you implement the collapse the column in the specific index? @Mateus Felipe
I did implement  flutter_staggered_grid_view, but the gridview did not rebuild the column width when the container has resize. :((

Comment: Yes, this example is very fixed, but it shouldn't be hard to generalize.

Answer (score 1):

How about you try below things?

1. Generate GridView with 2n item.
2. If there is a remain item, add a widget for last one item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) package for this.

Example:

```
 StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  itemCount: 8,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Center(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text('$index'),
        ),
      )),
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
      StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
)
```

1. Return span count for last row as 1 inside the `staggeredTileBuilder`
2. Return Centered widget for the last row inside the `itemBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

You can use StaggeredGridView

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
    itemCount: totalCount,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Center(
        child: Container(
          width: w,
          height: w,
          color: Colors.redAccent,
        ),
      );
    },
    staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
        new StaggeredTile.count(index == totalCount-1 ? 2 : 1, 1),
)
```