# Horizontally Center Last Odd Item of Gridview or ListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, gridview

[image]

Horizontally Center Last Odd Item of Gridview or ListView

I tried staggeredGridView but it doesnt have alignment.

Comment: i think this may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558934/centering-the-last-row-of-items-in-a-flutter-gridview

Comment: i posted another answer as well @Muhammet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centering the last row of items in a flutter gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558934/centering-the-last-row-of-items-in-a-flutter-gridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code :

```
SizedBox(
                  height: h * 0.4,
                  child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    itemCount: 7,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
                        child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                        height: w / 4,
                        width: w / 4,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            index == 6 ? "C" : "$index",
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
                    staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
                        StaggeredTile.count(index == 6 ? 3 : 1, 1),
                  ),
                ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here how i solved

[image]

```
SizedBox(
                  height: h * 0.4,
                  child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    itemCount: 7,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
                        child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                        height: w / 4,
                        width: w / 4,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            index == 6 ? "C" : "$index",
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
                    staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
                        StaggeredTile.count(index == 6 ? 3 : 1, 1),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: bro you can not post your own answer please read the guildline of stackoverflow

Comment: Asker can not post the answer

Comment: I know but this is the best option i think. Can you post my answer so anyone can see?

Comment: Yes wait ... doing

Comment: Done please check and delete your answer