# How do I center items inside a GridView.Builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, grid

I have a GridView.Builder with a crossAxisCount of six it works well when there 12 items but if the items are 11 or less or just uneven it doesn't look so well... [image: 11 Items do not look so nice]

this is what it looks now NOT SO NICE with just eleven items

This is what I would like it to look like when there is less items

[image: The items that are less should fall on the center]

the items that are less should fall on the center, this way when it is maybe just one item it should not show on the far left but it should just be on the center like this...[image: single item apear on the center]

and here is my code

```
GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: staffs == null ? 0 : staffs.length,
              gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  childAspectRatio: 1.0, crossAxisCount: 6),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      showPinDialog(staffs[index]);
                    },

                    child: Container(
                      // padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                      margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, bottom: 5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          border: Border.all(
                              color:
                              Colors.white)),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment:
                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.asset(
                              'assets/icons/black/user.png',
                              width: iconSize,
                              height: iconSize,
                              fit: BoxFit.contain
                          ),
                          Center(
                            child: Text(
                              '${staffs[index]['name'][0].toUpperCase()}${staffs[index]['name'].substring(1)}',
                              // staffs[index]['name'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: staffNameFontSize,
                                color: Color(0xff000000),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

                              ),
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              maxLines: 2,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                );
              },
            )
```

Comment: It's May help https://stackoverflow.com/a/57955465/11427294

Answer (score 0):

[GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) doesn't seem to have an alignment property for its items. A workaround for this use case is to use a `ListView` and use `Wrap` for its rows to help them align in center. A sample is demonstrated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73122008).