# make last row of grid-view builder centre align in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-layout

I want to center align the last row of the grid view as sometime due to having less number of element it is not full

[image]

Comment: Can you include what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Wrap` widget in case,

```dart
class G extends StatelessWidget {
  const G({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      final width = constraints.maxWidth - (8 * 16); //for spacing

      return ListView(
        children: [
          Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
            runSpacing: 8,
            spacing: 8,
            children: List.generate(
              13,
              (index) => Container(
                  width: width / 8,
                  height: width / 8,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text("$index")),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: yes we can do something like this, but I am using GridView builder it acts as a single widget, does not return children of the widget so cannot be used with wrap'

Comment: `Wrap` also a single widget and children can be populated my map,loop or List for children