# How to center GridView items inside a Column in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a `GridView.builder` inside of a `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollView`.  I cannot seem to get the items of the GridView to center horizontally inside of the Column.

I have tried adding `Center` to many parts of the widget tree and including `mainAxisAlignment` `crossAxisAlignment` and more parameters to each widget of the tree.  I have also tried wrapping the widget in a container with width infinity.  Other widgets placed in the column are centered, so I believe the problem lies within the GridView delegate.

MRE:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 40, crossAxisSpacing: 2.5),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: 9,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return const Text(
                    '_',
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The only relevant answer I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955051/how-to-center-gridview-items-in-flutter), however the complexity and code overhead seems unneccessary for such a trivial issue, and it is hard to scale the `Text` correctly.

Comment: You can add a Center parent to the Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap Column with Center widget and GridView with SideBox and set the size based on your need.

[link to the out put](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QGT8MFitzxeNPer4wX9dwppFrGwUIEny/view?usp=sharing)

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center( // Wrap center outside of column
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                width: 400, // The trick is here
                child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 40, 
                    crossAxisSpacing: 2.5,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 2.5,

                  ),
                  itemCount: 9,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      child: const Text(
                        '_',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```